# Computed property on individual record in ArrayController

Tags: ember.js

Let's say I have a `Person` model

```
App.Person = DS.Model.extend
  firstName: DS.attr 'string'
  lastName: DS.attr 'string'
```

And I have a route to display all people

```
App.Router.map ->
  @route 'people'

App.PeopleRoute = Ember.Route.extend
  model: ->
    @store.find('person')

App.PeopleController = Ember.ArrayController.extend

  # This doesn't work
  fullName: (->
    @get('firstName')
  ).property('firstName')
```

How can I define a `fullName` computed property in an `ArrayController` for each person in the array, so I can do something like this?

```
{{#each}}
  {{fullName}}
{{/each}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Array controller manage an array of objects, you can define an `itemController` to use additional methods in each item. Like this:

```
App.PeopleController = Ember.ArrayController.extend
  itemController: 'person'

App.PersonController = Ember.ObjectController.extend
  fullName: (->
    @get('firstName')
  ).property('firstName')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
fullNames: (->
  @getEach('firstName')
).property('@each.firstName')

{{#each name in fullNames}}
  {{name}}
{{/each}}
```

Answer (score 0):

On top of the other two answers, since asking the question I found a third solution as well.

We can put computed properties on the model itself, which allows us to call the method anywhere in our application.

```
App.Person = DS.Model.extend
  firstName: DS.attr 'string'
  lastName: DS.attr 'string'
  email: DS.attr 'string'

  fullName: (->
    "#{@get('firstName')} #{@get('lastName')}"
  ).property('firstName', 'lastName')
```